# What is the use of Scala Future.fallbackTo

Tags: scala, future

Given this code

```
val f1: Future[Int] = Future { 5 } //Future.failed(new Exception("sorry"))
val f2: Future[Int] = Future { 6 }

val result : Future[Int] = f1.fallbackTo {
  println("Fall back to that F")
  f2
}
```

result contains the result of f1. However the code in the fallbackTo block is executed regardless of whether f1 fails or not. I was expecting the fallbackTo block to be only executed if f1 fails.

Perhaps my example is too simple (or just wrong), but what is the use of fallbackTo?

Comment: This seems to be related to your problem: https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6913

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You are correct, `f1` is returned if it's successful, if not `f2`, the print you are seeing is because of the fact that the block is not evaluated lazily:

```
def fallbackTo[U >: T](that: Future[U]): Future[U]
```

So it seems that `f2` is started when it's passed to `fallbackTo` (and hence the print statement is executed). Probably it's a design choice, if it would have been lazily evaluated `f2` would have been started only after the failure from `f1`.

If you want to avoid this kind of behaviour you can use `recoverWith` which is fired only after a failure:

```
f1.recoverWith{ case _ => println(123); Future { 6 } }
```

Comment: In this case the f2 is run in parallel with f1.  To solve this the Future should be defined inside the recover/recoverWith body, or be a def instead of val

Comment: @roterl thanks, you are right, futures are started as soon as they are declared.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to force f1 failure explicitly:

```
 val f1 = Future.failed(new Throwable)

 val f2: Future[Int] = Future { 6 }

 val result : Future[Int] = f1.fallbackTo {
     println("Fall back to that F")
     f2
 }
```